# Android app resolution for tablets

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have recently added my app to google play store.
It has following resolutions set.

```
layout-sw600,
layout-sw720
```

However it seems that google play doesn't makes this app not to support 800*1280 devices. How can I put the resolution? simply by layout-sw800? It seems that there are hdpi etc too as per supporting multiple screens in android tutorials. Its all confusing, can anyone explain a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i do is name the folders like:

> layout-xlarge-mdpi ---> for 10.1 inch tabs.
>
> layout-large-hdpi ---> for 7 inch tabs with high density.
>
> layout-large-mdpi ---> for 7 inch tabs with medium density.

And of course you can add resolution after dpi.

Comment: WHAT additional directories do i have to make along with layout-sw600,
layout-sw720

Comment: if you use the above names than you cannot use layout-sw600, layout-sw720. Can you tell me what resolutions and devices are you targeting?

Comment: Then rename your folders to layout-xlarge---> for 10.1 inch tabs or greater.  layout-large ---> for 7 inch tabs or less. Hope this help you.

Comment: ayout-large-mdpi = 600 layout-large-hdpi = 720 and layout-xlarge-mdpi  = 800 right?

Comment: so in essence i have to make two folders ayout-large-mdpi and  layout-xlarge-mdpi

Comment: Yes you have to make two folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a specific layout for 800*1280 then you can use following layout directory name.

```
Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res) (160 dpi):

layout-xlarge (800 x 1280)
layout-xlarge-land (1280 x 800)
```